# how to add thousand separator for number input fields in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I want to add thousand separators to an number input however I don't want to change the value. I add the separators but the value will become string.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const addCommas = (num) =>
    num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  const removeNonNumeric = (num) => num.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  const handleChange = (event) =>
    setValue(addCommas(removeNonNumeric(event.target.value)));

    console.log(typeof value)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this code as soon as user enters a number, the typeof value will become string since we are using toString method.
I was wondering if there is a way to implement an input and only modify its view not its value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thousand separator input with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091317/thousand-separator-input-with-react-hooks)

Comment: no its not. this way changes the type of value to string.
I want to keep the type of value as number but shows the thousand separators at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this code solve this problem the code is below and another little thing i can say may be **none numaric string are not able to convert to number and the thing is that a comma as like none numaric string that's why you got NaN** see the code **solution:**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    displayValue: 0,
    actualNumberValue: 0
  });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const strNumber = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    setValue({
      displayValue: strNumber,
      actualNumberValue: Number(strNumber.replace(/,/g, ""))
    });
  };
  console.log(typeof value.actualNumberValue);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input type="text" value={value.displayValue} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It converts the number to NaN if it is greater than 3 digits.

Comment: please see my answer i just modified now.

Comment: It's not working.
First of all I want to have only 1 value.
Second the string value for input field will be something like this: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,000

Comment: i just update my previous solution with one more replace method and after that solve like this: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,000 issue but still first problem because can't possible **none numaric string to convert number** that's why i take two variable. Thank you dear